# Is there an Excel function that works the same as filter() from Google Sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a list of names that each have a value (C:C, D:D). I want to generate a new column (A:A) that only shows the names that have the values I want, without any spaces.

In Google Sheets it's trivial:

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

I'm moving to Excel due to some shortcomings with Sheets that I can't get around, and can't figure out how to duplicate this functionality. The closest I've come is with MATCH/INDEX, but I was never able to get there. All of the research I've done has pointed to needing VB, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Shortcomings with Sheets? I'm a long term google sheets user who now has to work with Excel online for a particular customer. And I find Excel online very limiting compared to Google Sheets in terms of functionality and speed.

Answer (score 5):

In Excel, one must put a formula in each cell that one is expecting a result.  So, the short answer is no there is no function in Excel that would exactly match the use of Filter in Sheets.

To do this I like to use INDEX with AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",C:C)))/($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",C:C))<>0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Put that in A1 and copy down till you get blanks.  As stated one must put a function in each cell that one expects a return.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this question, =FILTER now works in Office 365 versions of Excel along with some other dynamic formulas. Excel 2019 or earlier doesn't support this function and I don't think there's any plans to add the functionality into these older products.

Comment: Which versions exactly?

Comment: apologies - I have added more detail

Answer (score 1):

I know that @AutoBaker mentioned this, but here's an example for others that might require it.

So, yes, for @JoeFish's question you would only need:

`=FILTER(W4:W6,X4:X6<>0, "")`

However, if you wished to transpose values, then you can combine it with the `TOCOL()` or `TOROW()` functions. Strictly speaking these will also account for errors and remove them from your results as well:

`=TOCOL(FILTER(C:C,D:D<>0,""),3,TRUE)`

This would essentially make column values for the responses that the `FILTER()` function returns.

Note to others finding this, this works to fill adjacent cells. It's good for keeping cells *genuinely* empty, unless certain criteria are met.